# How do I see the queue of untagged faces in the 2015 Mac Photos App?

Tags: photos, photos.app

In the old iPhoto, I could go to a screen to see a queue of faces that hadn't been tagged, with tag suggestions.

In the 2015 Photos App, whilst I can tag photos, I can't find the bit where I get the tag suggestions, where you can see the queue of untagged faces.

My question is: **How do I see the queue of untagged faces in the new Mac Photos App?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Albums > Faces - the pending list should appear at the bottom of the page, if there are any new faces to tag.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This feature doesn't seem to be present in the current version of Photos.